# Python Pandas: aggregate large subset of columns without explicitly typing them out

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset, aggregation

I am trying to do an aggregation on my dataframe. The problem is I need to aggregate by over a hundred columns. Right now I have them all typed out like this

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['Column1'])['Column2','Column3','Column4','Column5'].sum()
```

up to the last column. Very tiresome and difficult to maintain, if changes have to be made. Is there a way to refer to these columns without explicitly typing them out?

Comment: Do you want to exclude any column besides Column1?

Comment: Yes, there are more columns in the dataframe that I neither wish to group by, nor sum up.

Comment: Don't forget to accept one of our answers if you found them helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a super simple way if you can select the desired columns with a condition. I use this method occasionally but not for >100 columns so I'm not sure of the performance implications.

For a sample df:

```
df
   a   b   c  bb
0  1   4   4   4
1  2   5   5   5
2  7  87  87  87
3  5   6   6   6
```

Using list comprehension:

```
df[[i for i in df.columns if 'b' in i]]
   b  bb
0   4   4
1   5   5
2  87  87
3   6   6
```

This can obviously be used with whatever condition you like.

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['Column1'][[i for i in df.columns if 'b' in i]].sum()
```

Using my super simple example, some side by side performance:

```
%timeit df[[i for i in df.columns if 'b' in i]]
1000 loops, best of 3: 394 µs per loop

%timeit df[df.columns.difference(['a','c'])]
1000 loops, best of 3: 598 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 5):

You can define the columns by difference:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['Column1'])[
    df.columns.difference(columns_to_exclude + ['Column1'])
].sum()
```

Note that the method `difference` uses sets, so the order of the columns is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize you could use any function between the [] brackets. Unfortunately I have to exclude almost as much as I need to include, but I guess I can use index references between the brackets as well?

Comment: It depends how you define the columns to exclude, but I'm sure the interface is quite flexible (see other answer for instance).